# Uncountable homogeneous linear orders

Tags: order-theory, model-theory, cardinals, automorphism-group

Let $(S,\leq)$ be a countable linear order with the following property (H):

for all positive integers $n$, and all increasing sequences $s_1 < s_2 < \ldots < s_n$ and $t_1 < t_2 < \ldots < t_n$, there is an order automorphism $\alpha$ of $S$ such that $\alpha(s_i) = t_i$ for all $i
= 1, 2, \ldots, n$.

Then by a result of Cantor, $(S,\leq)$ is order isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Q},\leq)$.

Now suppose that $S$ is not countable, but also having property (H). It seems to me that the order automorphism group of $(S,\leq)$ should share many properties with the order automorphism group of $(\mathbb{Q},\leq)$.

What are some of the important properties that they do **not** share ? What are the (main) differences ?

Answer (score 4):

One difference is the number of orbits of increasing length-$\omega$ sequences. This isn't really a difference in the automorphism groups per se, but rather their actions, but I think it's interesting enough to note.

---

In $Q=(\mathbb{Q},<)$ there are **exactly three** kinds of increasing sequence (up to automorphism, in the sense that any two sequences of the same type can be swapped by an automorphism of $Q$). Namely, an increasing sequence $(a_i)_{i\in\omega}$ of rationals has exactly one of the following three properties, and if $(a_i)_{i\in\omega},(b_i)_{i\in\omega}$ have the same property then there is an automorphism $\alpha$ of $Q$ such that $\alpha(a_i)=b_i$ for all $i\in\omega$:

- **Unbounded**: the set $\{a_i:i\in\omega\}$ has no upper bound.
- **Bounded but no least upper bound**: the sequence is bounded but whenever $b\in Q$ is such that $b>a_i$ for all $i$ there is some $c\in Q$ such that $c>a_i$ for all $i$ and $c<b$.
- **Has a least upper bound**: there is some $b\in Q$ such that $b>a_i$ for all $i$ and for all $c<b$ there is some $i$ such that $c<a_i$.

For example, taking $a_i=i$ yields a sequence of the first type, taking $a_i=\pi-{1\over i+1}$ yields a sequence of the second type (the "$+1$" addresses the case $i=0$), and taking $a_i=1-{1\over i+1}$ yields a sequence of the third type.

By contrast, this can fail for uncountable orders with property (H). For example, $R=(\mathbb{R},<)$ has property $(H)$ but only two types of increasing $\omega$-sequences (every bounded sequence has a least upper bound).

- As an aside, this is fundamentally impossible in the countable context: Vaught's [never-two theorem](http://www.logic.univie.ac.at/~vfischer/Michael_Zechner_thesis.pdf) says that no complete theory in a countable language can have exactly two countable models up to isomorphism. Gauging the number of models of a theory of a given cardinality is a major theme in model theory - for example, if $T$ is a complete theory in a countable language then the number of countably infinite models of $T$ is either finite, $\aleph_0$, $\aleph_1$, or $2^{\aleph_0}$. Every finite value other than $2$ is possible, as are $\aleph_0$ and $2^{\aleph_0}$; it is [unknown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaught_conjecture) whether (in case [$\aleph_1\not=2^{\aleph_0}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_hypothesis)) the case $\aleph_1$ is possible. It's also worth noting that there's a rephrasing of Vaught's conjecture that doesn't trivialize under the continuum hypothesis (see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/175987/how-do-we-know-if-vaughts-conjecture-is-absolute)).

Comment: @ Noah Schweber : I don't think I understand your statement about $(\mathbb{Q},\leq)$; let $(a_i)$ be an unbounded increasing sequence in $\mathbb{Q}$ which is dense as a subset of $\mathbb{Q}$, and let $(b_i)$ be the sequence of integers. How can those be order isomorphic by an order automorphism of $(\mathbb{Q},\leq)$ ?

Comment: @Boccherini An increasing sequence can't be dense, and the set of integers can't be enumerated by an increasing sequence either...

Comment: @AlexKruckman: oops, I am using the wrong definition for (increasing) sequence here, I guess -- is such a sequence by definition indexed over the positive integers ?

Comment: @Boccherini Noah was careful to specify that his sequences are indexed by $\omega$: the set of natural numbers.

Comment: @AlexKruckman: I am sorry to say that I am not used to that notation.

Comment: @Boccherini Here $\omega$ is the first infinite [ordinal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number). But your confusion is understandable: Logicians often forget that other people like to use the notation $\mathbb{N}$. :)

Answer (score 3):

We usually think of automorphism groups not just as groups, but as topological groups, under the topology of pointwise convergence. Then the automorphism group of any countable structure is a Polish group: it is separable and completely metrizable. On the other hand, if $M$ is an uncountable structure in which some point has an uncountable orbit (for example, if $M$ is an uncountable homogeneous linear order in your sense), then $\text{Aut}(M)$ has an uncountable family of disjoint open sets, so it is not separable.

Comment: @ Alex Kruckman : suppose $(a,b)$ is an open interval in $\mathbb{Q}$; then in the order automorphism group, we can consider automorphisms fixing all points of $\mathbb{Q}$ outside $(a,b)$, and which move an arbitrary point $c \in (a,b)$ to an arbitrary point $c' > c$ which is also in $(a,b)$. I have the feeling that such constructions also should work for linear orders $(S,\leq)$ with $S$ not countable, and where (H) is satisfied. Is there a general way to "transfer" such properties to the uncountable case ? (As you remark, not all "non-obvious" group-theoretical properties transfer.)

Comment: @Boccherini I don't have a general transfer principle in mind, but it's easy enough to prove the specific claim you ask about in your comment. Suppose $(S,\leq)$ is a homogeneous linear order (in your sense), with $a<c<b$ and $a<c'<b$ in $S$. Then by (H), there is an automorphism $\sigma$ of $S$ which fixes $a$ and $b$ and moves $c$ to $c'$. Define $\sigma'\colon S\to S$ by $\sigma'(d) = \sigma(d)$ if $d\in (a,b)$ and $\sigma'(d) = d$ otherwise. Then $\sigma'$ is an automorphism of $S$ which fixes all points outside $(a,b)$ and moves $c$ to $c'$.